# How to create subfolders in git branch?

Tags: git

I have a repo and I have created a branch like this:

```
git checkout -b AAA/BBB
```

It works well. Now I want to add some new things, and I want to create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b AAA/BBB/CCC
```

but I am getting an error:

```
error: unable to resolve reference refs/heads/AAA/BBB/CCC: Not a directory
fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: Not a directory
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? Can I do that? Is it bad? Why? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the things you may want to know. Assume we are now at master branch.

```
$ git checkout -b aaa/bbb
```

After this, you can see the newly created file under `.git/refs/heads/aaa/bbb`. Yes, when you create a branch, git will make new file under `.git/refs/heads`. So, if you use the branch name `aaa/bbb`, git will make the file, bbb under aaa folder. Does it make sense? So, after doting the following

```
$ git checkout -b aaa/bbb/ccc
```

You will getting an error because git try to make the file ccc under `.git/refs/heads/aaa/bbb`.

I recommend you to use not / on your branch name or just use only one / (e.g., issue/1234, issue/1276). Usually I use issue_1234 or issue1234 instead of /.

Comment: In fact that is what I want to do: to create a `.git/refs/heads/aaa/bbb/ccc`. If I do `git checkout -b ccc` under `aaa/bbb` is it creating `ccc` under `aaa/bbb`?

Comment: You can't because bbb is file. So you can't make a file ccc under the file bbb. I am just wondering why you want to do like that? I also did it 4 years ago, but right now as you know, you can't.

Comment: See the following also.

$ git branch aaa/bbb/ccc
$ git branch aaa/bbb/ddd
$ git branch aaa/bbb
error: there are still refs under 'refs/heads/aaa/bbb'
fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: Is a directory